# How to execute Macros Libreoffice Impress v.5?

Tags: libreoffice

I cannot figure out how to execute a macro in libreoffice impress.  I went to tools - advanced - enable macros, restarted the program and I still don't have any new options.  I am trying to execute a macro in a .bas file but when I go to run macro I can't find a way to execute the file saved to my home. There is nothing in the libreoffice documentation about executing a .bas file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't execute a macro directly from a `.bas` source file. Instead, you need to create a new library or a new module in an existing library, and copy/paste the Basic code into that new module.

Generally, there's a per-user macro repository and a system-wide repository. Additionally, you can put macros directly into LO Impress / Writer / Calc files, but they will only be available if that file is currently loaded.

So, the exact solution depends on the scope of your macro - do you use it only together with a certain impress file, or should other users use it, too?

For [more Information regarding how to organize macros in LO, see the LO Wiki](https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Organizing_Libraries_and_Modules).

Assuming you need it only combined with a certain impress file:

1. Open that impress file in LO; open the .bas file in a text editor;
2. In Impress: Menu `Tools` -> `Macros` -> `Organize Macros` -> `LibreOffice Basic`;
3. In the `Macro from` window, select your impress file; hit <kbd>New</kbd>; enter a module name;
4. Now, the LO Basic IDE opens, with a `Sub Main - End Sub` macro stub.
5. Copy the basic code from the .bas file, and paste it into the LO Basic IDE.

That's it. Now, you can start editing / debugging the macro code using the LO Basic IDE. Saving your Impress document will save the macro code, too. You can run the macro from Menu `Tools` -> `Macros` -> `Run Macro` -> Select your Impress file, Library ("Standard") and Module - select `Main` -> hit <kbd>Run</kbd>.